# How to get the first date with the first value, by country in a Dataframe - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to get the first date with value > 0 in a dataframe.

It seems like really simple, but I can't thing anything really clear. The thing is I need to get is grouped by country.

I have tried to use like that:

```
result.head(1000)
Out[5]:
                    Confirmed  Deaths  Recovered
Country/Region Date
Afghanistan    1/22/20        0.0     0.0        0.0
               1/23/20        0.0     0.0        0.0
               1/24/20        0.0     0.0        0.0
               1/25/20        0.0     0.0        0.0
               1/26/20        0.0     0.0        0.0
...                           ...     ...        ...
Austria        1/27/20        0.0     0.0        0.0
               1/28/20        0.0     0.0        0.0
               1/29/20        0.0     0.0        0.0
               1/30/20        0.0     0.0        0.0
               1/31/20        0.0     0.0        0.0

In [6]: result.query('Confirmed > 0').head(1)
Out[6]:
                        Confirmed  Deaths  Recovered
Country/Region Date
Afghanistan    2/24/20        1.0     0.0        0.0
```

but as you can see I've just can get the first value just for 1 country, and I want the first date with the first value > 0 for all dataframe.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need:

```
result.query('Confirmed > 0').groupby('Country/Region').head(1)
```